# Meaning of Azure Analysis Services memory metric

Tags: azure-analysis-services

The memory measure in the Azure Analysis Services Metrics page, is it the memory used by Azure AS after compression has been applied? I've loaded a 31 GB SQL DW table into Azure AS and the memory measure shows 24 GB. Is this the expected compression rate (23%)?

Answer (score 2):

The memory metric is the amount of memory used by your model after compression is applied.  If you are re-processing your model then more memory is used for a shadow copy, this also shows in the metric.

With regards to the expected compression ratio, the success of the compression processes depend on the number of distinct values in each column and how fast the values change from one row to the next (e.g. is the column sorted).  There is a very good explanation of these two factors in [Alberto Ferrari's presentation to a Swedish user group](https://youtu.be/q3CUb6FFsuQ?list=PLvV3N7Ps6eQ1QIS1j1KJll1HRr7XfQRdt), the first 25 minutes or so where he discusses run-length and dictionary encoding is the bit you want.

Comment: there's also a good explanation in Tabular Modeling in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (https://www.amazon.com/Modeling-Microsoft-Analysis-Developer-Reference/dp/1509302778), the Hardware Sizing a Tabular Solution whitepaper (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874401.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)